# how to simulatenously detect recv and send in tcp/ip programming?

Tags: c, tcp

I'm trying to create a simple messenger program and I've just covered the basics of tcp/ip socket programming with c.

but by including 'recv' and 'send' in a while loop, the client-server can only communicate one time per turn. I was thinking of making my messenger program to be able to send and receive any messages right away. for example, my program should be able to receive more than one messages if the other side is sending such many messages.

I guess this all comes down to the problem where the recv() and send() cannot be done separately inside a while loop.
How can I manage these functions to act asynchronously?

The plan B that I was thinking was to just have the server record all the messages among clients in a log file and make the clients synchronize its chat every second or so.

Is this what the practical messenger apps do or is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: You can eslect() on your socket to see when there is data received?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways people handle this problem in high performance network servers, but the way you're likely interested in is to use event-based I/O.

Basically any operating system you could be using on modern, non-embedded hardware has an event-based I/O API. In fact, there are usually a few to choose from:

- `select(2)`
- `poll(2)`
- `epoll(2)` on Linux
- `kqueue(2)` on BSD and OS X
- `portfs` or `/dev/poll` on Solaris and forks

Why use any of these over another? Both `select` and `poll` suffer from the problem that they copy large arrays of information into and out of the kernel every time they're called. This size increases linearly with respect to the number of concurrent connections.

The upside of these interfaces is that they're implemented everywhere; they're portable. In that respect, `poll` is generally preferred over `select` because the latter has a built-in limit on the number of file descriptors it can handle (generally bounded at 1024). In fact it is slightly worse than this for `select`: because it implements a bitmap where each bit represents an fd, it cannot even represent file descriptors larger than 1024. `poll` does not suffer from such a limitation.

The system-specific interfaces provide a more efficient means of doing the same thing that `poll` and `select` do, but obviously are not portable between systems. If you don't want to reinvent the wheel and write your own wrappers around these things, you may want to check out [libPhenom](http://facebook.github.io/libphenom/), [libevent](http://libevent.org/), or [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html).

Since it sounds like you're writing a multiuser chat server, the process is typically:

1. Poll sockets for readable data
2. Read data from sockets
3. Send data to other interested parties
4. Rinse
5. Repeat

If you are unfamiliar with [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/), it is a great resource for learning about the fundamentals. Indeed, he also has a [section on "advanced techniques"](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/advanced.html) that includes a tiny multi-user chat server.

Comment: I don't fully understand since I'm not good at this but it's a new start point! I'll look into it thanks!